# VB.NET - Reading a blank string from Excel when trying to read the header of a data column?

Tags: vb.net, excel

A simple though very odd problem. I use an OLEDB connection to read from an excel database, and this loop to read in all of the data from each of the columns

```
While reader.Read()

            For i As Integer = 0 To reader.FieldCount - 1
                temp = reader(i).ToString + ControlChars.Tab
                output_file.Write(temp)
                'output_file.Write(reader(i).ToString() + ControlChars.Tab)
            Next

            output_file.WriteLine()
        End While
```

Some of the columns contain date information, which are read in fine (usually as a string "2/20/2011" or so), but the headers of those columns are read in as a blank "". The headers for all the other columns read in fine, but not for the date containing columns. Any idea how I can fix this?

Comment: What do the column headers contain?

Comment: @aphoria Just strings as the names of the columns

Comment: Do you have HDR set to yes in your connection string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well here's the solution, which I stumble across accidentally. Your connection string needs "IMEX=1;" in it, which tells the reader that all data types should be read as strings.

```
Dim jet_string As String = "provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + input_file_path + ";Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=No;IMEX=1;"""
```

Comment: Setting IMEX will only be of much use if you tamper with the registry. Also, it is only relevant with mixed data types. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257819

Comment: Also - I tried this and it made no difference (admittedly in an ODBC connection string).

Answer (score 0):

Is it because OLEDB is inferring type for the date columns (DateTime or whatever) and the headers to do not conform to this type? I've had similar issues with ODBC ignoring the odd alpha string in a column that is otherwise numeric.

Comment: It's possible. Were you able to get the problem fixed?

Comment: @cost - no, ended up having to prefix all data with an alpha char and then strip it off again once imported.

Comment: Check out the answer I posted, it might help you in the future